# Declaring a constant in java

Tags: java

I have come across something rather strange today. A java developer has declared a constant like this:

```
public final class Constants {

 public static final String KEY_COLUMN = AbstractDataRow.standardiseColumnName("key");
   ... // rest of implementation      
}

public abstract class AbstractDataRow implements IRow {
    public static String standardiseColumnName(String columnName) {
        return columnName.trim().toLowerCase();
        ... // rest of implementation
    }
}
```

What is strange to me is that `KEY_COLUMN` calls a method from an `abstract class`.

Is this good practice?

Comment: Why do you think it's strange?

Comment: It's not how I would do it, but before I answer *yes* or *no*; define "good"?

Comment: If you take under consideration Single Responsibility Principle, method standardiseColumnName should be extracted from AbstractDataRow. Method's responsibility is only to convert column name to the 'standard' format what is completely out of data row representation. To be sure need to look at whole code.

Comment: the method that is called is static. So no need for an instance. It may make more sense to have it somewhere else but the developer may have a reason. Ask about it

Comment: @shmosel Strange because it don't see this often

I was thinking more the lines of using a static block initialiser to initialise the variables

Comment: any `// rest of implementation` after a `return` statement is unreachable code.  But what is really strange to me is that `standardiseColumnName()` appears to be just a long winded wrapper of `trim()` and `toLowerCase()`, and neither or those operations are necessary on the input value `"key"`.  Why not just assign the value `"key"` directly?  The program should only need to "standardize" actual user input.

Comment: Also, that is not a constant in Java terms.

Comment: As I suspected, there are many problems with the code I just encountered. I am looking for someone to suggest a better idea to initialise a static final variable (constant) without calling a static method from an abstract class. Seems like the constant is coupled with another static method in some other abstract class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answering your question.. Not really.

You could just as easy call that string into the method already defined.. then convert that string to lowercase.

send the string to the method instead of the method to the string.